# Nativescript Angular injecting font awesome icon code into field

Tags: angular, icons, nativescript

Hei guys. I am trying to inject and font awesome code () which is a lock icon into an Label text's but it does not render the icon, but only the string is shown.

```
 <Label class="fas" [text]="myIcon"></Label>
```

So this will print on the screen: '&# xf023;'

Hardcoing the string value would show the icon :

```
 <Label class="fas" text="&#xf023;"></Label>
```

Comment: What is the value of `myIcon`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript equivalent of the HTML / XML entity `&#xf023;` is `String.fromCharCode(0xf023)` hence

```
myIcon = String.fromCharCode(0xf023);
```

Comment: I have answered the same :)

Comment: Sorry, I think in your answer you are using char code with HTML entity value which I guess may not work.

Comment: Actually this does work either because the method expects an number, not a string, so i order to work, should remove the ''. Still, this is the correct answer, thank you

Comment: You were right, the quotes are not required and if you are using TypeScript it will throw an error. I was not realising the quotes when I originally posted it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `myIcon = '&#xf023;'`, you should pass `myIcon = String.fromCharCode(0xf023)`

If you are using Angular then you can create a pipe as well to transform, if you don't want to use `String.fromCharCode` in all your .ts files.

Comment: I just ran a small test and confirmed this fails. `String.fromCharCode(...)` method expects a number not a string, therefore it will return only empty string for `String.fromCharCode('&#xf023;')`. @Angelo, perhaps you could confirm if this really works.

Comment: You can use fromCharCode(parseInt(‘f023;’,16))